# Screenshot not created | Unity3d, Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I am trying to create a screenshot feature for my Android-Game in [Unity](https://unity3d.com/).
I got this from code from various sources that and it should work, however I can't find the picture in the file-browser or the gallery for that matter.

```
void capture(){
    foreach (GameObject i in hideOnCapture) {
        i.SetActive (false);
    }

    //Application.CaptureScreenshot ("screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss") + ".jpg"); 
    StartCoroutine(ScreenshotEncode ());

    foreach(GameObject i in hideOnCapture) {
        i.SetActive (true);
    }
}

IEnumerator ScreenshotEncode() {
    string save_Address = "screenshot_" + DateTime.Now.ToString ("yyyyMMdd-hhmmss");
    Texture2D texture1;
    byte[] bytes;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame ();
    texture1 = new Texture2D (Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    texture1.ReadPixels (new Rect (0 , 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
    texture1.Apply ();
    yield return 0;
    bytes = texture1.EncodeToPNG ();
    File.WriteAllBytes ("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/" + save_Address + ".jpg", bytes);
}
```

I want to save the screenshot to gallery. What do I need to do?

Comment: did the app ask for file system rights during the installation?

Comment: @Minzkraut I installed it using "build and run" in Unity which uses adb to sideload apps onto the device, so I don't get this dialog. I'll test it though.

Comment: did you check if the path is correct? e.g. my phone doesnt have the "/mnt/" part"

Comment: @Minzkraut it doesn't ask for file system permissions. :/  I don't know what the right path is. Is there a universal path to the Picture folder on Android?

Comment: I don't think so, i will take a look at an app i made a while ago later... maybe i can find the part where i saved my image.

Comment: sorry, what i remembered was just a sharing function.

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25150 might be a plugin worth looking at (the cheapest) i guess

Comment: Thank you for the tipp. I am going to use this plugin. I also forgot to set the Write Access to External (SDCard) in the Player Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't solved the issue using my own code.
The [plugin](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25150) suggested by [Minzkraut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3948598/minzkraut) (thank you!) is just too cheap, powerful and easy to use.

However the reason for my problem might have just been not setting *`Write access`* to 
*`External (SDCard)`* in the *`Player settings`*, but I am not sure about that.

[image]

Comment: don't know if this is related, but on iOS i have to take out the spaces. so we do something like this path = path.Replace(" ", "%20"); hope it works for you